# Can't get post_custome('item') in foreach on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Custom Post Types in WordPress. I would like to display primary categories, secondary categories, and custom posts associated secondary categories.

The issue is that `post_custom('price')` doesn't work although `<?php the_title(); ?>` shows. I couldn't understand why it doesn't work.

```
<?php 
  $my_tax = 'area'; 
  $parent_terms = get_terms( $my_tax, array('hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0) );  //第一階層のタームだけ取得
  if ( !empty( $parent_terms ) ) :
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $parent_terms as $pt ) : 
      $pt_id = $pt->term_id;
      $pt_name = $pt->name;
      $pt_url = get_term_link($pt);
?>

    <?php 
        $child_terms = get_terms( $my_tax, array('hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $pt_id) );
        if ( !empty( $child_terms ) ) :
        echo '<ul class="child">';
        foreach ( $child_terms as $ct ) : 
            $ct_id = $ct->term_id;
            $ct_name = $ct->name;
            $ct_url = get_term_link($ct);?>  

            // It worked
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>

            // Doesn't work
            <p><?php echo post_custom('price'); ?></p>
    <?php
        endforeach;
        echo '</ul>';
        endif;
    ?>

<?php
    endforeach; 
    echo '</ul>';
  endif;
?>
```